# How to assign a model with dynamically generated keys to a directive in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Suppose I have a scope object like:

```
$scope.user = {
    pets : {}
}
```

, an element like this:

```
<my-pets 
    id="pets" 
    my-model="user.pets"
    data-title="Pet name" 
    data-types="dog, cat, bird, hamster, exotic">
</my-pets>
```

and a directive like this:

```
app
  .directive('myPets', function() {
    return {
      restrict : 'E',
      replace : true,
      scope : {
        id : '@',
        myModel : '=',
        title : '@'
      },
      templateUrl : 'pages/directives/mypets.html',
      link : function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var pet_types = attrs.types.split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < pet_types.length; i++) {
          pet_types[i] = pet_types[i].trim();
        }

        scope.pet_types = pet_types;
      }
    };
  });
```

With a template like this one (using the material directives):

```
<div>
    <label>{{title}}</label>
    <md-tabs>
      <md-tab ng-repeat="pet_type in pet_types">
        <md-tab-label>{{pet_type}}</md-tab-label>
        <md-tab-body>
          <md-input-container>
            <label>{{pet_type}} {{title}}</label>
            <input ng-model="---what should go here?---" id="id-{{pet_type}}" type="text"/>
          </md-input-container>
        </md-tab-body>
      </md-tab>
    </md-tabs>
</div>
```

The model, right out of the angular controller, looks like this:

```
$scope.user = {
    pets : {}
};
```

But I'm trying to achieve a structure like this one:

```
$scope.user = {
    pets : {
        dog : '',
        cat : '',
        bird : '',
        hamster : '', 
        exotic : ''
    }
};
```

The pet types are passed as an attribute `data-types`. The model doesn't know yet which types it should hold, because in the future it should be possible to add more pet types on the fly. So, the idea is to pass to the directive an `ng-model="user.pets"`, and the directive should be smart enough to take the pet types passed by parameter `data-types`, and create one input per type, that was linked to each attribute inside `user.pets`.

You may have already noticed the `---what should go here?---` in the template. Now, according to that, and provided I pass a `my-model` to the uncompiled directive with an object, and knowing that this object should contain as keys the pet types, and as values the user input per each pet type, how should I do so? I tried this one: `ng-model="{{myModel}}.{{pet}}"`, but it complains about a `{` here, so I guess I can't generate model names on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reference the root of your model in an `ng-repeat`.

Your model is `pets` in this case, not `myModel`.

The right way to access scope variables in an `ng-model`-directive in this case is:

```
<input ng-model="pet" id="id-{{pet}}" type="text"/>
```

You could also access the looped object via root object:

```
<input ng-model="pets[pet]" id="id-{{pets[pet]}}" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Ahhhhh the second example makes a lot of sense, but since I don't know in the directive which is my model until it's passed to the directive, should I still use the scoped version of the model? E.g. `ng-model="myModel[pet]"`?

Comment: The two lines both use scope models, actually. Just in the first, you access the child object referenced by ng-repeat, so you don't have to repeat yourself. In the second one, you reference the whole scope model. How do you want to adapt the template to the potentially changing model in the directive?

Comment: Well, according to the initial design, the model doesn't know per se which _pet types_ it has until they are assigned in the directive, so the second one makes more sense to this design. An yet still, `my-model` is designed as `user.pets`, but it could be any other field also related to pets, say `user.favorite_pets` or `user.allergic_pets`. That's why I'm concerned you used `user` as the model, and not the agnostic `myModel`. Anyway, that's something I'll definitely test, to know which case fits the best

Comment: Ok, maybe the line `scope.pets = pets` is key here? Then the key is still`<input ng-model="pet" id="id-{{pet}}" type="text"/>,` but 2nd one is  `<input ng-model="pets[pet]" id="id-{{pet}}" type="text"/>`. Will update the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the poor naming, `scope.pets` is a list, coming from `data-types`. It would be the same as `['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'hamster', 'exotic']`. I changed its name to `pet_types`, and added the real, better defined, goal in the question